# Automation For AWS Cloud formation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Is there any way to automate the cloud formation in Amazon Web Services?I thought of using Shell script but if we consider five resources like (1 VPC,2 Subnet,4 EC2,1 ELB,S3) then lots of parameter need to be added in shell script.Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Unfortunately, your question is unclear. Please Edit your question and add more detail to your question. For example, what do you mean by "automated CloudFormation"? Are you referring to automatically creating the template, or do you wish to create resources in AWS without using CloudFormation? Please provide some examples so we can understand your question better (just hit Edit to add some detail). Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

AWS CloudFormation (https://aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/details/) allows you to define AWS resources in a declarative way. For example to create an instance:

```
{

    "Description" : "Create an EC2 instance running the Amazon Linux 32 bit AMI.",

    "Parameters" : {

        "KeyPair" : {

            "Description" : "The EC2 Key Pair to allow SSH access to the instance",

            "Type" : "String"

        }

    },

    "Resources" : {

        "Ec2Instance" : {

            "Type" : "AWS::EC2::Instance",

            "Properties" : {

                "KeyName" : { "Ref" : "KeyPair" },

                "ImageId" : "ami-3b355a52"

            }

        }

    },

    "Outputs" : {

        "InstanceId" : {

            "Description" : "The InstanceId of the newly created EC2 instance",

            "Value" : {

                "Ref" : "Ec2Instance"

            }

        }

    },

    "AWSTemplateFormatVersion" : "2010-09-09"

}
```

If you could be more specific in your question then maybe someone can assist further.

Comment: i want it to automate this.This is manual process for creating template.

Comment: @shalu Automate what? The creation of the CloudFormation template from existing resources?

Comment: @jbird Automate in the sense,to provide only resource name like EC2, VPC not the whole configuration.I want to give only name of resources i needed.By Automate Cloud Formation template ,i mean to say that i provide resources name and template created automatically.

Comment: No, you can't do that within AWS tools, CLI or console at the moment. I'm also not aware of 3rd party tools to automate template creation. For a graphical way to create the template you can use CloudFormation Designer https://console.aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/designer. Guide - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/working-with-templates-cfn-designer.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use then some of plugins from text editors: For Atom atom.io/packages/… For sublime 3 github.com/beaknit/cform

Comment: Thanks @momo but i have 1 doubt will it create all resources like EMR also.

Comment: @shalu Sorry what do you mean by EMR ?

Comment: By EMR : resources to create cluster.

Comment: @shalu What is ur question ? :)

Comment: I want some automation for template creation where i only need to give resource name.For example ,if i want to create rds engine Aurora.I will prove engine name and version and simple template is created.

Comment: You can use then some of plugins from text editors: 

For Atom
https://atom.io/packages/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=keyword:cloudformation

For sublime 3
https://github.com/beaknit/cform

Comment: Thanks. Thats what i was looking for @momo